# How to keep typed in values on a select box after submitting the form

Tags: php, forms, error-handling

I want to keep the selected value after submitting the form. Because, in case of form errors, I want to keep the inputs not removed. It works from number 1 to 5. But the sixth option does not POST the value after submitting. It posts an empty field.  Do you know why?

```
        <script>        
                $(document).ready(function(){
                    $("#select").change(function(){
                        $("input[name='percent']").val($(this).val());
                    });
                });
        </script>
              <select id="select" name="selector">
            /*1*/     <option>Choose</option>   
            /*2*/     <option  value="10% ">10% </option>
            /*3*/     <option  value="20% ">20% </option>
            /*4*/     <option  value="33% ">33% </option>
            /*5*/     <option  value="50% ">50% </option>
            /*6*/     <option  value=" <?php echo $_POST['selector'];  ?> ">other</option>
                </select>
                <input type="text" name="percent"  id="input"
                <?php  if(isset($_POST['selector'])) { echo "value=".$_POST['selector'].""; } else { echo "placeholder=\"Type in other options\""; } ?> >
```

Comment: Maybe because its `value` attribute was empty to begin with ... have you _checked_ whether you code outputs a value as you expect in that place to begin with?

Comment: It is empty to begin with, but the user types the value into the input box. I want the input box value should appear here: <option  value=" <?php echo $_POST['selector'];  ?> ">other</option>

Comment: Well then you probably need to start by accessing the right value to begin with. Your input field has the name `percent`, so it will _not_ be found under `$_POST['selector']` ...

Comment: I have changed the sixth option to this: <?php if($_POST['percent']) { echo $_POST['percent']; } ?>  but it still posts empty.

Comment: And have you now finally _checked_ whether that created any actual content inside the value attribute of that option? That this could possibly only ever set an option value if the user filled out the text field first and submitted the form is clear, right?

Comment: It echoes the value as a clean text, but not in the following: value="<?php if($_POST['percent']) { echo $_POST['percent']; } ?>" .

Comment: Well. I see it now. The echo worked. But the selected option "other" is not selected by itself.  It prints out the value when I select it manually. The problem is whether I can get the selected option automatically after submitting?

Comment: If you want to have an option selected by the default, then you must give it the `selected` attribute. _"The problem is whether I can get the selected option automatically after submitting?"_ - you get the value of the selected option ... because that is how forms work.

Comment: I know. Something must be missing. It just does not output the value if I don't select it manually. Even when I am using the attribute selected="selected", it outputs empty. Looks like it must be selected manually to get the value.

Comment: No, that is not the case. Regarding form submission, there is no difference between an option that had the `selected` attribute set, and one manually selected by the user. Selected is selected, the browser does not care how or by whom.

Comment: I see. I must try to get the wanted selected item to get selected. And get the value of it into the input box.

Comment: Thanks. I guess I solved this now.

Answer (score 0):

"Other" is just the name displayed, the value being sent is `$_POST['selector']` -- so if that's empty, and empty value is being sent!

Comment: I know but $_POST['selector'] for options 1 to 5 is the same. And it gets the value from them. But it does not get the input value from the sixth option.

Comment: It doesn’t get one, because you never gave the option a value to begin with. (Or to be more precise, you gave it an _empty_ value, so that’s what it submits.)

Comment: It is true. Now I have tried the following to the sixth option:      <option  value=" <?php if($_POST['percent']) { echo $_POST['percent']; }   ?> ">other</option>
Still posts empty...

Comment: You're on the right track. Now you need to specify an ELSE block what value to use when $_POST is empty!